# Need macro to write the formula in a cell not the answer (ouput)

Tags: excel-formula, output, formula, cell

I cannot figure this out - I either get a Named? error or Application defined error on trying everything.

```
Dim sAmt As Integer
Dim sOriginalAmount As Integer
sOriginalAmount = ActiveCell.Value
sAmt = Application.InputBox("How much additional cost?", Type:=2)
ActiveCell.Formula = sOriginalAmount + sAmt
```

What I want Excel to do is write the formula in the cell not the output.

For example - Currently if I have sOriginalAmount as 15 and I enter sAmt as 20, on running the code, it gives the answer 35 in the cell, but I want it to write =sum(*valueof*sOriginalAmount + *valueof*sAmt) so that at a later time I can see what was the original amount and how much was added.

Can anyone please help? I have tried & "" in various combinations but I just can't get it. Apologies for such a noobie question, but I am self learned and I code for my work only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```VB
ActiveCell.Formula = "=" & sOriginalAmount & "+" & sAmt
```

Or if you actually want to use SUM.

```VB
ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUM(" & sOriginalAmount & "," & sAmt & ")"
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much.